# Weirdness exporting constants created with enum::fields in perl

Tags: perl, enums, exporter

I've created two test modules, `X.pm` and `X2.pm`.  The `X.pm` module works.  The `X2.pm` module doesn't, at least not like I'd expect it to.

X.pm

```
package X {

    use enum::fields qw(I_VAL);
    use parent qw(Exporter);

    our @EXPORT = qw(I_VAL);
}
```

X2.pm

```
package X2 {

    our @EXPORT = qw(I2_VAL);

    use enum::fields (@EXPORT);
    use parent qw(Exporter);

}
```

The test program is:

```
use X;
use X2;

printf("I_VAL = %d\n", I_VAL);
printf("I2_VAL = %d\n", I2_VAL);
```

And the output is:

```
bash$ ./tmp/testit
I_VAL = 0
Undefined subroutine &X2::I2_VAL called at /home/bennett/tmp/testit line 15.
```

The real project has several dozen `enum::fields`, and `X2.pm` is my attempt to keep the enumerations in sync with the exports.

My questions are these:

- Why doesn't `X2` work?  Is it exporting(importing) before
  `enum::fields` runs?
- What do I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use statements are executed as soon as they are compiled, so

```
use enum::fields (@EXPORT);
```

is executed before

```
our @EXPORT = qw(I2_VAL);
```

This would work:

```
package X3;

use strict;
use warnings;

my @enum; BEGIN { @enum = qw( I2_VAL ); }

use Exporter     qw( import );
use enum::fields @enum;

our @EXPORT = @enum;

1;
```

Comment: Splendid!  This works like a champ.  Why?  Is it because the other way, the assignment wasn't executed until after `use enum::fields` had already been run?

Comment: Yes, so `@EXPORT` was empty